# DOM - assigning random number to manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom, random, png

I am trying to get a function to repeat the code of a seperate eventListener. The event listener merely performs the proces once. The while loop intends to complete the process 'num' times. Whilst the eventListener button works, and will assign the "dice-" + dice + ".png" correctly and display the appropriate graphic file, the the while loop does not. It generates a random .png file, and displays this num times, even whilst each iteration does produce a new random number. I have named the variables for each case seperately to avoid confusion.

```
document.querySelector(".btn-roll").addEventListener("click", function() {
    //1. Rnd number
    dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

    //2. Display the result
    var diceDOM = document.querySelector(".dice");
    diceDOM.style.display = "block";
    diceDOM.src = "dice-" + dice + ".png";
    console.log(diceDOM);
});

//roll dice num times
function rollDice(num) {
    var i = 1;
    var dice2 = 0;
    while (i < num) {
        //1. Rnd number
        dice2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        console.log("Dice: " + dice2); //error checking. dice2 is producing new number each loop iteration

        //update diceDOM with new dice value
        var diceDOM2 = document.querySelector(".dice");
        diceDOM2.style.display = "block";
        diceDOM2.src = "dice-" + dice2 + ".png";
        console.log(diceDOM2); //error checking. diceDOM appears to be set on calling loop fist time (not set by dice var, but an alternative random number)
        i++;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Bug found - or, no *actual* bug present.

In order to see the change occurring, the diceDOM2.src needs to be console logged specifically. For some reason console printing the whole object does give the updated src!